# AutoLayout + UITableViewCell + Height (not worked)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout

I am trying to autoresize table cell with autolayout.
But it seems TableView ignores height constraints.

I know that "tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:" can do this.

But how to avoid to use height hardcoding ?
Is any other ways ?

screen shot 1:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/3spak2koe2s6jif/1.png]

screen shot 2:

[image: [https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dnumxqv28bjh939/2.png]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pNxL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"YourCell"];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath]; // making text assignment and so on
    return [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: This is generally a really bad idea. `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every single row in the tableView. If you have more than a couple of cells in the tableView this will have a huge performance impact.

Comment: Matthias Bauch, this solution just changed the order of cell creation. Instead of creating the cell in the "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" it's created the cell in the "tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:" and reused in "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:". So nothing to worry.

Comment: The performance problem is not the cell dequeuing, or the creation (which happens one time only). The performance hit comes because you trigger the layout process for each row. If this solution works for your case feel free to use it. But as I said, it's generally a bad idea. If you use code like this in a tableView with hundreds of rows you will feel a massive performance impact. `t:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` should run as fast as possible.

Comment: If you need a custom row height with auto layout cell it is the best solution, I guess. of course the better to have a predefined row height but it is not universal

Comment: Calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, woah... don't DO that. It is messing up the way `UITableView` sets itself up.